# Regex split rows with newline, keep split keys

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I need to split a large text at the end into separate conversations. All conversations start with date and time. How can I split using regex by date+time, but still keep date and time in the text, and not actually split it from the rest of the text?

Details:

```
// Sample text:
22/06/2019, 21:54 - Name 1, (N: Si mute  sa nu mai ma vibreze
22/06/2019, 21:55 - Name 2: Comunicat de interes public.
 "Pentru o viata sănătoasă sunt recomandate aceste setari."
22/06/2019, 21:55 - Name 3: 
24/06/2019, 18:14 - Name 2: Sa va explic, eu pana acum nu m-am jucat cu WhatsApp îndeajuns dar am cautat prin el acum si am descoperit ca  are muulte semne mai mult sau mai putin utile printre care si asta . acum intrebarea  e daca semnu  asta face referire la propozitia de mai sus sau e ce ne gandim cu totii? 
25/06/2019, 10:11 - Name 1: psd?
```

I tried using a simple '\n' like below, but it failed as some of the conversations have newline included:

```
$arrRows=stringData.split(/\n/); 
// this does not work for the item below, as it will split it into 2 conversations and I need to keep it as 1
'22/06/2019, 21:55 - Name 2: Comunicat de interes public.
 "Pentru o viata sănătoasă sunt recomandate aceste setari."'
```

So instead of that I tought about using Regex and split by date/time at the begining of each line, so I used this:

```
const regexRow=/(?<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}), (?<time>\d{2}:\d{2})/;
$arrRows=stringData.split(regexRow);
```

, which is ok, but I need to keep the date and time in the text to parse it at a later stage, using the code below for each row:

```
const regexi = /(?<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}), (?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}) - (?<person>.*): (?<link>https?[^ ]*)?(?<rest>.*)/;
```

Answer (score 3):

To preserve the date/time in the results, you can split on a newline with a forward lookahead for the date/time at the beginning of the next line:

```js
const stringData = `22/06/2019, 21:54 - Name 1, (N: Si mute  sa nu mai ma vibreze
22/06/2019, 21:55 - Name 2: Comunicat de interes public.
 "Pentru o viata sănătoasă sunt recomandate aceste setari."
22/06/2019, 21:55 - Name 3: 
24/06/2019, 18:14 - Name 2: Sa va explic, eu pana acum nu m-am jucat cu WhatsApp îndeajuns dar am cautat prin el acum si am descoperit ca  are muulte semne mai mult sau mai putin utile printre care si asta . acum intrebarea  e daca semnu  asta face referire la propozitia de mai sus sau e ce ne gandim cu totii? 
25/06/2019, 10:11 - Name 1: psd? `;

const lines = stringData.split(/\n(?=\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}, \d{2}:\d{2})/)
console.log(lines)
```